# How to create text block on image using just CSS

Tags: html, css, textblock

I wanted the effect from this article: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

But I want to know how to do it when defining the image in CSS instead of HTML.

If I make a new line that is longer than the previous line it creates a block of background colour which is the same length as the new line, for both lines.

What's the proper way of achieving this effect (without setting up the image in HTML)?

===Additional info===

This is what I was trying earlier..

HTML:

```
<div class="img-main-wide">
    <span class="img-text-green">
            "be bold, and venture to be wise."<br />"Begin, be bold, and venture to be wise." 
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-main-wide{
    background-image: url(../images/Pyramids-Egypt.jpg);
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}

.img-text-green{
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 1em;
        top: 10em;
        left: 0;
        color: white;
        padding-right: .5em;
        padding-left: .5em;
        background-color: rgba(51,102,0,0.8);
        font-size: 36px;
        font-style: oblique;

}
```

Comment: So `background-image` instead of `<img>`?

Comment: just use a span and give it background-image and do the same as mentioned in tutorial

Comment: might be being stubborn but is there a way of doing it without the h2. Is that relevant? can I not just use div and span? The only thing I can't get to work is the background colour sticking to text on a new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `position: absolute` to `span`, you implicitly set `display: block` to it. So absolutely positioned `span` doesn't behave like text selection any more and behaves like a solid rectangle instead.

To solve this, you can use two nested `span`s: the outer one for positioning and the inner one for text formatting. E.g.:

HTML:

```
<div class="img-main-wide">
    <span class="img-text-green">
        <span>
            "be bold, and venture to be wise."<br />"Begin, be bold, and venture to be wise."
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* .img-main-wide code is not changed */

.img-text-green {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1em;
    top: 10em;
    left: 0;
}
    .img-text-green > span {
        color: white;
        padding-right: .5em;
        padding-left: .5em;
        background-color: rgba(51,102,0,0.8);
        font-size: 36px;
        font-style: oblique;
    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2RG7/)

Another option is just not to use `position: absolute`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2RG7/1/)

Comment: Perfect. Was about to ask why the extra span is necessary but you explained it well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
div{
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("your-image-url") no-repeat;
    /*define width and height also*/

}
.textblock{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: is background-color not appearing on text-block, if then use overflow: hidden or apply clearfix method.

Comment: It gets the effect but when I enter a new line the background colour becomes a big block rather than sticking to the text on each line

Comment: tried both but doesn't seem to make a difference (apply to .textblock, right?)

Comment: ah I should have put it in jfiddle earlier. When there's a new line the text background colour doesn't stay behind just the text. It goes further to the right than the text on each line (I want it to be just behind the text, like when you're highlighting)

Comment: Oh! you wanted to be inline-block, just wrap your text with `<em>` and apply background-color there http://jsfiddle.net/tUxV7/1/

Comment: ah yes that's another way that works, but I guess using <em> is somewhat less general than span?

Comment: yes but I was thinking that using span is more adaptable than using em because em signifies emphasised text and span could be whatever you want it to be. Maybe it's just personal preference but I like to be general so that I can adapt my code easily if needed